# Error while running on GCP: unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'

Tags: python, keras, google-cloud-platform, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to create an RNN for character recognition and prediction using a book as an input. It was taking a few minutes to run each epoch on my local machine, so I tried to run it on GCP.

I'm getting the following error while executing my code on Google Cloud Platform. But the code is executing normally when I try on my local machine using Spyder3.

```
# Character Prediction using RNN
# Small LSTM Network to Generate Text for Alice in Wonderland
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils

# load ascii text and covert to lowercase
filename = "Alice in Wonderland.txt"
raw_text = open(filename).read()
raw_text = raw_text.lower()

# create mapping of unique chars to integers
chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# summarize the loaded data
n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)
print ("Total Characters: ", n_chars)
print ("Total Vocab: ", n_vocab)


# prepare the dataset of input to output pairs encoded as integers
seq_length = 100
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = raw_text[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i + seq_length]
    X_train.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
    y_train.append(char_to_int[seq_out])

n_patterns = len(X_train)
print ("Total Patterns: ", n_patterns)

# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train), seq_length, 1))

# normalize
X = X / float(n_vocab)
# one hot encode the output variable
y = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)


# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')



# define the checkpoint

filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]


# fit the model

model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

The error is occurring while creating the LSTM, on the following line:

```
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
```

This is the Error:

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2957, in rnn
    maximum_iterations=input_length)

TypeError: while_loop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue while running on my local machine. Below are the steps i followed

My conda environment name is TESTENV

1. Login or enter into your conda enviroment using

   ```
    source activate TESTENV
   ```
2. Check if pip is already installed in the conda enviroment, else install it

   ```
    conda install pip
   ```
3. Install TensorFlow version 1.4.1

   pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.1-py2-none-any.whl
4. Install Keras version 2.1.2

   `conda install keras=2.1.2`

Comment: Had the same issue. Was running tensorflow version 1.4.0 and had installed latest Keras with pip, but had to uninstall that and reinstall Keras version 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

```
conda remove keras*
conda install keras-gpu==2.1.6
```

solved my same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your tensorflow.The problem will be solved.

```
CPU：pip install –upgrade tensorflow
GPU：pip install –upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```